# Is there any software that I can do real time motion capture in Blender with?

Tags: motion-capture

I just finished an animation, and it took me a really long time. I was thinking of ways to reduce the time, and motion capture crossed my mind. I was wondering if anyone knows of any real-time motion capture software that works with Blender.

Answer (score 1):

There are trials you can play with here https://ni-mate.com/ and here http://ipisoft.com/. Extra functionality, you might have to pay for...

Comment: Ok thank you! I will look into IPI soft. I already tried Ni mate and it didn't work.